# What is the proper way to perform Latent Class Analysis in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I'd like to model a data set using [Latent Class Analysis](https://methodology.psu.edu/downloads/lcastata) (LCA) using Python. I've found the [Factor Analysis](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html#examples-using-sklearn-decomposition-factoranalysis) class in sklearn, but I'm not confident that this class is equivalent to LCA.

Does a package or class for LCA exist in Python?

Comment: LCA is an important topic, so here's what I found:
Single class implementation, relaying on numpy and scipy

    https://github.com/dasirra/latent-class-analysis

Python implementation with examples:

    https://www.advancedrrmmodels.com/latent-class-models

May be after a while I will validate those or come up with own code.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, there is no package that provides LCA support in python. There are, however, many packages using different algorithms to perform LCA in R, for example (see the [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/index.html) directory for more details):

- BayesLCA Bayesian Latent Class Analysis
- LCAextend    Latent Class Analysis (LCA) with familial dependence in extended pedigrees
- poLCA    Polytomous variable Latent Class Analysis
- randomLCA    Random Effects Latent Class Analysis

Although not the same, there is a [hierarchical clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering) implementation in sklearn, you could check if that suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

[StepMix](https://github.com/Labo-Lacourse/stepmix) provides LCA models in Python. Features include an sklean API and support for missing values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).